# meaning of "'" (apostrophe) in terminal commands

Tags: command-line, syntax

For some weird reason, I tried "'" as word separator in identifiers, as in:

```
$ export foo'bar=1
> 
> ^C
$
```

The result is as shown above, *id est* the prompt changes to ">" and the system obviously waits for more information on my part. As you see, I had to ctrl-C to escape. The same happens using other commands such as

```
$ ls foo'bar
$ mkdir foo'bar
```

I'm curious about the sense of all this, that is what special meaning "'" has in terminal commands (so special in fact that it is taken apart even inside ids).

*Extra:* As an aside I would also like to know the set of special or otherwise invalid characters in file and folder names, both under Unix-like and Windows systems (to get the common subset of safe ones) (in particular, what about all non-ASCII?).

Thank you,
Denis

Comment: In the Linux world, all characters except for \0 (null) and / are permitted. However, that doesn't mean they're all advisable. Many people consider it best to avoid characters that have a special meaning to the shell. If you want to know about Windows, consult a Windows reference.

Answer (score 15):

The ' character  is a very powerful character whenever used in any shell command. Basically the ' (apostrophe marks) disables all kinds of transformations or modifications. It would consider whatever is enclosed with the ' marks as a single entity i.e. a single parameter. Absolutely no sort of substitution or expansion would take place.

Example:

```
 $ echo '$HOME'
```

would produce at the output the string `$HOME` itself and would not print the path to your home directory. Since the single quotes prevents any sort of expansion, substitution and simple considers whatever to be present as a simple parameter in itself.

If you want to use the apostrophe as it is, you have to escape it:

```
 $ mkdir foo\'bar

 $ cd foo\'bar
```

If it is not escaped, it will wait for it's pair to be closed, like it happened in your first example.

So, corrected, your command will be:

```
 $ export foo\'bar=1
```

**NOTE:**
As Milan Todorovic noticed, this will not be valid, because you cannot use apostrophe in this case.

Comment: @denis63 please accept the answer if it is what you needed to see :)

Answer (score 7):

Character `'` is a special character. You use it to mark part of command line entry that won't be changed (e.g. no replacement for wildcards). For example:

```
$ ls 'bla*'
ls: cannot access bla*: No such file or directory
```

This means that argument for `ls` was `bla*` and not everything that begins with `bla`.

The reason why you get `>` character is because you must use one `'` for opening and one `'` for closing part that won't be changed.

If you want to use `'` in folder names you must escape it like this: `\'`. So if you want to list folder named `foo'bar` you should type `ls foo\'bar`.

Oh, and I'm not sure if it is possible to use `'` in environment variable names. I think that you cannot use `export foo\'bar=1`,

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upvote for your observation about environment variable name restriction.

Comment: Can't upvote yet (new to askubuntu), but the feeling is there. Checked about env var names, it's just as you say. (I feel a bit stupid not to have thought at opening/closing delimiters myself, but I then considered "'" as a real apostrophe, not single-quote). Denis